# Problem closing Sweet Alert Library which has a timer

Tags: ajax, countdowntimer, sweetalert

Am working on an application build using Laravel. I have a payment page which is designed in a way when the user clicks on payment button, I trigger sweet alert Library with a message that the user should check his phone. The sweet alert popup also has a countdown timer for 60 seconds that works fine.

When the timer is counting, I am pushing the payload to the backend via AJAX whereby I consume the payment gateway API (which initiates STK push to the phone of the user with payment details).

When the payment is successful, I need to close the sweet alert popup box and redirect to another page which am unable to do. Kindly assist?

```
<script>
//When payment button is clicked
$("#payment").submit(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        //Initiate sweet alert library with a countdown timer of 60 seconds
        var timer = 60,
        isTimerStarted = false;

        (function customSwal() {
            swal({
                title: "Message Sent",
                text: "Please Check your Phone..." + timer,
                timer: !isTimerStarted ? timer * 1000 : undefined,
                showConfirmButton: false,
                closeOnClickOutside: false,
                showCancelButton: false,
            });
            isTimerStarted = true;
            if(timer) {
                timer--;
                setTimeout(customSwal, 1000);
            }
        })();
        //END sweet alert

        //Fetch data from form
        var token = $('#token').val();
        var phone = $("#phone").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();    
        var plan = $("#plan").val(); 
        var amt = $("#amount").val();     

        var type ={
            'token': token,
            'phone' : phone,
            'email' : email,
            'plan' : plan,
            'amt' : amt
        };

        // console.log(type);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "payment",
            data:JSON.stringify(type),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response){
                //On success
                if(response == 'suc'){
                    //Add code to remove the sweet alert popup

                    //Page to redirect to
                    window.location.href="success" ;
                }
            },
            //Alert errors from backend
            error: function(data) {
                //console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
    //END submission
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try `swal.close()`?

Comment: @Musa  Thanks alot it works,,  I have added cancel button on the sweet alert popup but when clicked the sweet alert popup does not close